# Reusing MySqlConnection.serverString

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection

Say I have a connection to a database. After reading some stuff I want to connect to the same database. So I naturally use the first database mysqlconnection.serverstring

Well guess what, the password and username is not included in connect1.ConnectionString. So how can I do so? Is this by design?

```
      Using connect1 As New MySqlConnection(ConnectLocalhost.serverString)
            connect1.Open()
bla bla bla
                Using connect2 As New MySqlConnection(connect1.ConnectionString) ' this won't work
                    connect2.Open()
                End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put Persist Security Info = true in your original connection string otherwise it won't be read back.

Course if you do that you might as well not have a user name and password...

Answer (score 1):

1. Store your Connection String in your configuration - as It need to be changed outside the code (for example - production vs development).
2. Write an function that returned a active connection or wrapper object, so you can use:

   ```
   Using MyHelper.GetConnection()

      ...

   End Using
   ```
3. In this way, you can use connection and close it, as the connection pooling save the connection for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just re-use your original connection?  Unless you have explicitly closed it, you should still have access.

Comment: Depends on a few things that, and it shouldn't be the default way to go.

Comment: @Jim Thio : you are mistaken - one connection can definitely be used multiple times.  It is a instance of an object referencing your database (hence the 'new' keyword).